# The type of the object created with a help of Object o = "";

Tags: java

Say, there is a following example:

```
class Super {
    public int i = 3;
    public void m(Object o) {
        System.out.println("Object  " + i);
    }
    public void m(String o) {
        System.out.println("String  " + i);
    }
}

public class Sub extends Super {
    public Sub() {
        i = 5;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Super s = new Sub();
        Object o = "";
        s.m(o);
        s.m("");
    }
}
```

The result of this code is:

```
Object 5
String 5
```

But I thought it would be:

```
String 5
String 5
```

Don't quotes set String as this object's type? There are definitely some cases of casting to String with a help of quotes, so I'm a little confused about this basic example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you shared all of the code? I don't see a variable named sb.

Comment: It's supposed to be `s`, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the method is determined in compile time, and not in run time. The [dynamic dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch) exists only for the "parameter" `this` - there is no dynamic dispatch for parameters in [static typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_typing) languages such as java.

The compiler "choses" which method should be invoked, and since `o` is of type `Object` - it choses `m(Object)` - it has no way to know that the dynamic type of `o` is actually a `String`.

If you are interested - a common way to overcome this issue in some cases is using the [visitor design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

In your specific case, in order to "force" the activation of `m(String)` you should use `m(o.toString())`

Comment: @JohnDoe: You are most welcome, I hope this point is clear. If you need more clarification on the difference between "static type" and "dynamic type" please ask. If you already know the difference - I think this answer should have cleared the issue at hand for you, but you are welcome to ask for more details if something is not clear yet.

Comment: Yes, I did know the difference between dynamic and static typing (actually, I think that static typing is so much more easy to comprehend), but somehow missed this point in the example above. I'll surely see into the visitor pattern.

Answer (score 2):

In `sb.m(o)`, you're calling m() with an Object reference, so Java chooses that overload. Java will not choose a more specific overload than the reference type you pass it. It will go up the inheritance chain though. Say you didn't have m(String o), calling `sb.m("Hello")` would still be legal, but it would call the object version.

If you were to do `sb.m((String) o)`, you would get your expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You declared the object as `Object` so its type is `Object`. Types in Java are strong and static so when you declare an object as type `Type` that is what its type will be for life.

If you want it to be a string you'll have to use a `toString` method or a cast `(String)o`

Answer (score 0):

You are downcasting the String to an Object. What you are doing is similar to this.

```
public class Sub extends Super {
    public Sub() {
        i = 5;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Super s = new Sub();
        Object o = "";
        System.out.println("Object Type = " + o.getClass().getName());
        s.m(o);
        s.m((Object)"");
    }
}
```